# dynamically updating the layout Android

Tags: android-layout, android-camera, android-image

I am designing a layout in which i have 3 buttons at the center of the screen and a grid view at bottom f the screen. in the grid view i am adding images. but when i am adding images the buttons are fixed at their places and after many images gridview start covering the buttons starting from bottom. is there any way i can dynamically adjust the screen when the number of image increase.

my activity.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:andriod="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/address1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="locate yourself"
        android:onClick="address"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="photo"
        android:onClick="takePicture"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="place order"
        android:onClick="confirm"/>


</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center">
```

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make your RelativeLayout as LinearLayout. Try it and tell us the result.

Comment: how to position the buttons at the center of the screen then?

Comment: use gravity parameter to do that. For each Button add a gravity parameter for ex. left, right, centre. Try it.